# Regular expression to find particular pattern

Tags: regex

I'm a beginner in regex and trying to create regular expression (doing tests using c++/boost::regex_token_iterator) to find particular pattern:

```
(* some *)(* interesting *) (*test *) (* regular*)(* expressions *) (*  and *)
```

I want to find words, which much exactly to (* xxxx *) pattern, for single case i'm using below expression:

```
\(\* .+ \*\)
```

but cannot figure out how to apply it to string similar to above example. I want to get as result:

```
(* some *)
(* interesting *)
(* expressions *)
```

Following fragments should not be taken:

```
(*test *)
(* regular*)
(*  and *)
```

Any help is highly welcomed.

Comment: A regular expression on its own matches or not, it doesn't have output. How you get a list of results is going to depend on the programming language you're using, so you should show some C++ code. You've also described what you _want_ to happen, but not what's happening now; try to be specific so people don't waste your time and their own telling you things you already know.

Comment: Robercie, your `\(\* .+ \*\)` pattern implies there can be any char in between `(*` and `*)`. Is it true you do not expect the whitespaces inside and just want to match letters or digits or underscores in between `(*` and `*)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest one:

```cpp
\(\*\s\w+\s\*\)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```cpp
\(\* [^\s()](?:[^()]*[^\s()])? \*\)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BuUSDv/1/)

**Details**

- `\(\*`  - a `(*`  string
- `[^\s()]` - any char other than whitespace, `(` and `)`
- `(?:[^()]*[^\s()])?` - an optional occurrence of any zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` and then any char other than whitespace, `(` and `)`
- `\*\)` - a  `*)`  string

Comment: @Robert So, you always have just a single word, no spaces inside `(*` and `*)`?

Comment: Yes Wiktor, something like that.